# Parse xml form different nodes by id

Tags: xml

I need to parse this xml and get last-name by Id(99999) or by Id(55555) based on what I set in the method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldata
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS">
    <recordset name="object" nritems="1" acl="AW">
        <record name="object" id="99999" acl="DW">
            <field name="last-name" acl="TW">**SS**</field>
        </record>
        <record name="object" id="55555" acl="DW">
            <field name="last-name" acl="TW">**Jony**</field>
        </record>
    </recordset>
</xmldata>
```

I am trying this but get only firsr value

```
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(responseBody);
String subjectID = document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null).getAttribute('id', '');
String name;
for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null).getChildElements()) {
    if (xmlNode.getAttribute('name', '') == 'name') {
        name = xmlNode.getText();
    }
}
System.debug(
        subjectID
);
System.debug(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
    .getChildElement('recordset', null)
    .getChildElement('record', null).getChildElements()) {
```

Should be:

```
for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
    .getChildElement('recordset', null)
    .getChildElements() { // These are 'record' elements
```

And from there, you can parse the fields.

As an aside, you can use my [XmlToJSON](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2016/01/converting-xml-to-native-objects.html) logic to get a slightly-easier-to-work-with JSON structure instead.

Comment: Pls specify how to get last-name from record 55555